# Test Velocity Template

Tags: json, templates, velocity

I do have a velocity template something like

```
<TABLE>
<TH>
  NAME
</TH>
<TR>
   $!{name}
</TR>

  .....other code......

#foreach( $!{grade} in $!{student.gradeList} )
    <tr>
        <td align="center">$!{grade.mathGrade}</td>
        <td align="center">$!{grade.scienceGrade}</td>
    </tr>
#end
```

below is my json file

```
{
  "name":"xyz",
     ...other variables....
}
```

So, now I want to test this, but I am getting error that `Variable $student has not been set`. I checked that $student is not defined anywhere else in template. I tried to give random string value for that something like `"student":"XYZ"` but then it gave error that String does not have property named gradeList.  How to solve this?

Comment: you have `student.gradeList` that need to be available and for each grade also `mathGrade` and `scienceGrade`

Comment: @user7294900 So are you trying to say that in my json file I need to provide them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, where I added student as an object in my json file something like:

```
{
"name": "XYZ",
"student": {
    "gradeList": [
        {
            "mathGrade": "A"
        },
        {
            "scienceGrade": "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

}